# Everything works but i have : Notice: Uninitialized string offset,

Tags: php, arrays, string, notice

I need your help because my code works, it do what i exepcted but i have this : Notice: Uninitialized string offset. But i have no idea of how change that to make the notice disappear. If someone can help me, i would be grateful !
Have a great day everyone.

There is my code :

```
$bool = false;
    $chaine = $_POST['search'];
    for($i=0; $i<= strlen($chaine); $i++){
        if($chaine[$i] == " "){
            $bool = true;
        }
    }
```

And i got this on my page :

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 8 in
>   /navbar.php on line 47

But it works fine.

Thanks for theses quick answer ! It's works fine whithout the notice now, i didn't checked the value of strlen who it started at 1, that's why.

Comment: You run from "0 to strlen", but it needs to be "0 to strlen - 1".

Comment: note that `strlen()` doesn't return the number of characters, but the number of bytes. [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) can be more accurate

Comment: Yes there is many option to solve my error, thank you for your answer,and ok, i will check for mb_strlen()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to replace <= with < so that it doesn't exceed the length:

```
$bool = false;
    $chaine = $_POST['search'];
    for($i=0; $i< strlen($chaine); $i++){
        if($chaine[$i] == " "){
            $bool = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh thank you haha, i really need my coffee right now.